# AWS Lambda and NodeJS Cluster

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda

I wrote this short example to test clustering in AWS lambda.  Can someone tell me where I went wrong?  The number of cores returns 2, but the message is never passed.

```
'use strict';
var cluster = require('cluster');  
var http    = require('http');  
var os      = require('os');

var numCPUs = os.cpus().length;

exports.test = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log('Number of Cores : ', numCPUs);
    if (cluster.isMaster) {
        for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; ++i) {
            cluster.fork();
        }
        for (const id in cluster.workers) {
            cluster.workers[id].on('message', messageHandler);
        }
    } else {
        process.send('running');
    }
};

function messageHandler(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
}
```

Comment: Did the fork requests actually succeed? Do you have multiple cluster workers?

Comment: It seems to have, it spawns two IDs.

Comment: Wonder if your Lambda environment terminated when the handler function returned, and that took the forked processes with it. May need to modify the Lambda code so that it doesn't complete until the forked processes all complete.

Comment: Good idea. I'll test and let you know. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you try setting `context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;` ?

Comment: Not sure what you ultimately want to accomplish, here.  The machine may report 2 cores, but that doesn't seem particularly meaningful:
 http://stackoverflow.com/a/34219048/1695906