# Mutiprocessing in AWS Lambda

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I was trying to trigger lambdas concurrently using Dynamodb streams with ProcessPoolExecutor. This is the error I received.

The scenario is when a bunch of records(like 1000 records) fall into dynamodb(batch size 10), the streams trigger a lambda. I used ThreadPoolExecutor before and it worked but out of 10 processes in a batch only 5-8 records are processed and remaining are left.Each records takes around 50 seconds to finish. is it the 5 mins limit of AWS lambda that is skipping the other records in ThreadPoolExecutor. Also, using ProcessPoolExecutor will help my problem with ThreadPoolExecutor???

```
    [Errno 38] Function not implemented: OSError
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/var/task/ycf_calculator.py", line 464, in main
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=25) as executor:
    File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 390, in __init__
    EXTRA_QUEUED_CALLS)
    File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/context.py", line 102, in Queue
    return Queue(maxsize, ctx=self.get_context())
    File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 42,in __init__
    self._rlock = ctx.Lock()
    File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/context.py", line 67, in Lock
    return Lock(ctx=self.get_context())
    File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 163, in __init__
    SemLock.__init__(self, SEMAPHORE, 1, 1, ctx=ctx)
    File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 60, in __init__
    unlink_now)
    OSError: [Errno 38] Function not implemented
```

Comment: How to resolve these kind of error in lambda ?

Comment: AWS lambda lacks of `/dev/shm`, that is why you are seeing the above error when using `ProcessPoolExecutor`. See: [No shared memory](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=219962). Shared memory among processes is not supported in AWS lambdas. The limit has been changed to 15 minutes so `ThreadPoolExecutor` should work even if AWS did not allocate more than 1 CPU for your lambda.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using one invocation to process a batch of 10 records. Each record taking around 50 seconds to process. Without parallel processing, 50 * 10 = 500 seconds.

Lambda has a maximum execution time of 300 seconds.
Lambda virtually runs on one processor/core so multiprocessing between multiple CPUs isn't supported. (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34135359/whats-the-maximum-number-of-virtual-processor-cores-available-in-aws-lambda) for more insights.)

The thing is, you are not doing it the *Lambda* way.

What I would recommend is to split your existing Lambda into two different Lambdas (a **batch processor** and a **worker**).

The *batch processor* Lambda is triggered by your DynamoDB stream (with batch size 10 as in your example). This Lambda then *asynchronously* invokes the *worker* Lambda **for each** of the 10 records in your stream. (Important: Pass only **one** record for each *worker* invocation.)

The *worker* Lambda receives and process **one and only one** record independently. That's all it does.

In short,

```
1 dynamoDB stream -> 1 batch invocation -> 10 worker invocations
```

It is greatly simplified. No need to mess with multithreading or multiprocessing.

And you get 10 CPU cores for free!

Comment: how would you get and process results of the 10 worker invocations? That has to be in parallel as well otherwise we would end up with the exact same issue.